# What is the type of string_type for filesystem::path constructor?

Tags: c++

In the documentation for std::filesystem at cppreference it shows the path constructor taking a string_type&&. I'm looking for the constructor that just takes an ordinary (const) char* character pointer. It doesn't say anywhere what type string_type is. I'm wondering whether it'll implicitly construct an std::string when passing a const char* to it. The constructor in question here is [number 4](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/path) .

```
path( string_type&& source, format fmt = auto_format );
```

Comment: "*It doesn't say anywhere what type string_type is*" - Yes, it does, on the [main `std::filesystem::path` page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path), normally it's `std::wstring` on Windows and `std::string` everywhere else.

Passing `const char *` (or a different string type) should invoke a different constructor: (5)

```
template< class Source >
path( const Source& source, format fmt = auto_format );
```

Comment: So I guess each time it constructs a wstring, it dynamically allocates a new string each time yeah? Nothing I can do about that?

Comment: @Zebrafish It's going to store a `wstring` (on Windows) internally, no matter how you construct it. But passing a `const char *` to the constructor should construct that underlying string directly (that is, without allocating a temporary string).

Comment: What I mean is that when I pass it a const char* the string is allocated somewhere in memory already, by constructing a wstring it dynamically allocates extra buffer of memory and copies the string into it. That's what it does when it constructs a wstring, right? If it had treated it as a wchar_t* it probably wouldn't have need to dynamically allocate memory.

Comment: @Zebrafish No, it should allocate dynamic memory regardless.

Comment: Unless the string value is small enough to fit inside a Short-String-Optimization buffer, if `wstring` implements one.